# How to deploy php application to a live web server using ant and git

Tags: php, git, deployment, ant, build-automation

I need a solution that I can deploy php application to a webserver using ant and git. I need to copy the files to the webserver and run a php script which setup the database.

I was thinking about using sshexec to run commands which will update the files and run the php script

```
<target name="deploy">
    <sshexec host="host"
         port="22"
         username="user"
         password="****"
         trust="true"
         command="..."/>
</target>
```

Does anyone has the complete solution? or even a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to periodically copy a changing set of files to the server and to execute a known script after each update, you could use `git push` for copying and a `post-receive` git hook (http://book.git-scm.com/5_git_hooks.html) to invoke the script.

Comment: Hi, Do you have an ant script example?